# Parse android Local Data Store not working

Tags: android, parse-platform

In my android app I have this in the application class

```
Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);

// Add your initialization code here
Parse.initialize(this, getResources().getString(R.string.ParseAppID), getResources().getString(R.string.ParseClientID))
```

And it works fine for Parse Cloud, but for local datastore I am facing a problem in save the data. Here is a sample code for inserting an object and retrieving it after that,

```
 final ParseObject chatObject = new ParseObject("chats");

        chatObject.put("usernum", ContactPhone);
        chatObject.pinInBackground();

        ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("chats");
        query.fromLocalDatastore();
        query.whereEqualTo("usernum", "ContactPhone");
        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
            @Override
            public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {
                Log.d("CHAT447","DONE CALLED");

                if (e == null) {
                    for (ParseObject thisOb : objects) {

                        ChatID = thisOb.getString("objectId");
                        Log.d("CHAT447", ChatID);


                    }
                } else {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
```

The done function is not being called at all, so I dont know the problem is in pinning the object or in retrieving it?
Also can parse local data store used as replacement for SQLLite?

Thanks in Advance